# How to use Google API related javascript inside an LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, google-map

Is there any way we can use Google Address plugin related javascript inside an LWC component like we have used inside the Visual force pages like below,

```
<apex:component >
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"> 
</script>
<script>
function initialize(addressType) {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
    // to geographical location types.
    if (addressType == 'Test') {
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document
                .getElementsByClassName('test')[0]), {
            types : [ 'geocode' ]
        });
        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
        // populate the address fields in the form.
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed',
                function() {
                    fillInAddress('test');
                });
    }
    else {
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document
                .getElementsByClassName(addressType)[0]), {
            types : [ 'geocode' ]
        });
        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
        // populate the address fields in the form.
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed',
                function() {
                    fillInAddress(addressType);
                });
    }
}
</script>
</apex:component>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You cannot have direct CDN in LWC component. Download the file , create static resource and refer it in LWC component using [loadScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-resource-loader/documentation).
2. [Create CSP Trusted Sites](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=csp_trusted_sites.htm&type=5) to google sites so that the static resource js can interact with host site.
3. Note that I found bug some days back that just by above steps, it may not work. Not sure if its fixed now. So, the workaround is to [Whitelist Third-Party Hosts for Lightning Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_security_csp_whitelist.htm&type=5). You can do it in any community. I know it sounds weird that for accessing it in normal lightning experience, you need to add it in community, but this is just a work-around if above 2 steps does not work.