# CORS problem in Lightning

Tags: lightning, callout, httprequest, cors, get

My Lightning component makes 'GET' callouts for two different URLs of the same service.

For one it goes correct each time: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://integration.visma.net/API/controller/api/v1/Customer//invoice

For another, it fails: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://integration.visma.net/API/controller/api/v1/customerinvoice//print

Here is the error message from console:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://integration.visma.net/API/controller/api/v1/customerinvoice//print' from origin 'https://internetvikings--partactual--c.visualforce.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

How to make both to work properly?
[image]

Comment: So, the bug has not yet been fixed - see my [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/308904/70823) which would probably fix yours too