# How to include and use an external CDN in Lightning Web Components?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, css, html, css3

I'm trying to use an external javascript library in my lightning web component, this include two external CDNs one css and one js.

How can I load them in my component?

Answer (score 5):

Repasting from [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/308904/70823)

1. You cannot have direct CDN in LWC component. Download the file , create static resource and refer it in LWC component using [loadScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-resource-loader/documentation).
2. [Create CSP Trusted Sites](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=csp_trusted_sites.htm&type=5) to google sites so that the static resource js can interact with host site.
3. Note that I found bug some days back that just by above steps, it may not work. Not sure if its fixed now. So, the workaround is to [Whitelist Third-Party Hosts for Lightning Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_security_csp_whitelist.htm&type=5). You can do it in any community. I know it sounds weird that for accessing it in normal lightning experience, you need to add it in community, but this is just a work-around if above 2 steps does not work.